# jinja2 json template omiting <key : "value"> pair

Tags: python, jinja2

I am using jinja2 templating for rendering data in json

I have python data as

```
name = ['Mark', 'Smits', 'Roger']
age = [23, 45, 32]
gender = ['male','male']
```

I want to write it to json files using the following template

```
{
  "resourceType" : "MyData",
  "name" : "{{human_name}}",
  "age" : "{{age}}",
  "gender":"{{gender}}"
}
```

what i want is for the entries [Roger,32,(null)]

my output json file should look like:

```
{
  "resourceType" : "MyData",
  "name" : "Roger",
  "age" : "32",
}
```

Presently it looks like

```
{
  "resourceType" : "MyData",
  "name" : "Roger",
  "age" : "32",
  "gender":"",
}
```

I tried using filters in jinja but not really working.

Comment: Something like: `print(json.dumps([dict(name=pn) for pn in name]))`

Answer (score 0):

The thing is cleaning empty keys after generating a dictionary. I managed to do that by using a loop but there might be a better way to do this.

```
name = ['Mark', 'Smits', 'Roger']
age = [23, 45, 32]
gender = ['male','male']

item_count_max = max(len(name), len(age), len(gender))

name = name + [None, ] * (item_count_max - len(name))
age = age + [None, ] * (item_count_max - len(age))
gender = gender + [None, ] * (item_count_max - len(gender))

import json
for n, a, g in zip(name, age, gender):
    data = {
        'resourceType': 'MyData',
        'name': n,
        'age': a,
        'gender': g
    }
    items = data.items()
    for k, v in items:  # We remove empty keys here
        if not v:
            data.pop(k)
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```